# Pesquisar intervalo de data e hora PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, data, lógica

Supondo que exista um intervalo de datas ex: `2019-02-22` e `2019-02-26`
Eu preciso pesquisar no banco de dados por data e horário(preciso que extraia o valor por data e horário específico, por exemplo somente das 05:00 ás 13:30).
Gostaria de fazer isso:

```
  "SELECT tempo FROM manutencao WHERE data BETWEEN '2019-02-22 05:00:00' AND '2019-02-22 13:30:00'";
Guarda o resultado em uma variável;
    "SELECT tempo FROM manutencao WHERE data BETWEEN '2019-02-23 05:00:00' AND '2019-02-23 13:30:00'";
Soma o resultado com a variável anterior
    "SELECT tempo FROM manutencao WHERE data BETWEEN '2019-02-24 05:00:00' AND '2019-02-24 13:30:00'";
Soma o resultado com a variável anterior
    "SELECT tempo FROM manutencao WHERE data BETWEEN '2019-02-25 05:00:00' AND '2019-02-25 13:30:00'";
Soma o resultado com a variável anterior
    "SELECT tempo FROM manutencao WHERE data BETWEEN '2019-02-26 05:00:00' AND '2019-02-26 13:30:00'";
Soma o resultado com a variável anterior
```

será que eu tenho que fazer um `FOR` ou um `WHILE` para ele criar esse laço de repetição?

Tentei fazer tudo isso em uma só linha do *sql* mas sem sucesso.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi bem a questão mas acho que você pode usar algo do tipo:

```
SELECT SUM(tempo) from manutencao where DATE(Data) BETWEEN DATE('{$data_inicial}') AND DATE('{$data_final}') AND TIME(Data) BETWEEN time('05:00:00') AND TIME('13:30:00');
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno @Bruno, até daria certo, porém ali onde vc colocou SUM(tempo), não é um campo de tempo, o que teria que fazer é a seguinte conta, existe o campo hora_parada e hora_retorno, os campos são DATETIME, supondo que uma maquina parou dia '2019-02-22 09:00' e voltou dia '2019-02-22 15:00', seria 04:30 de maquina parada no dia 22/02 (das 05:00 ás 13:30); E supondo que a mesma maquina parou dia '2019-02-23 10:00' e voltou dia '2019-02-23 11:00', seria 01:00 de maquina parada no dia 23/02 (das 05:00 ás 13:30); 

portanto a "soma" das paradas seria 05:30
Entende?